# Trying to create a liquidity pool on local network using uniswap's contract's

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, uniswap, router, liquidity

I am trying to create a liquidity pool on my local network. Here is what I have done so far:

1. I deploy a WETH token
2. I deploy the uniswap factory
3. I deploy the uniswap router using the factory address and the WETH address
4. I deploy the 2 ERC20 tokens I want to create a liquidity pool for.
5. I mint those 2 tokens to my wallet.
6. I approve the uniswap router to spend my 2 tokens.

Before doing this step I verify that the router has enough allowance and I have enough of the 2 tokens in my wallet

7. I call the addLiquidity function

I get this error:
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.

Am I doing something wrong? What steps am I missing?

Uniswap v2 router: https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02

Uniswap Factory v2: https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/factory

For WETH and the 2 ERC20 I am using: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

EDIT: If anyone wants to try, here is a link to my files. Import them to Remix to try.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ckw_vKlvGwl9IebQAlWymIRE7z8hIlVz?usp=sharing